# Synchronization across classes

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, synchronized, critical-section

I have two threads running concurrently, a main thread and a listener that implements `Runnable`.

The main thread and listener each have a critical section, specifically the method `getObjectList(String)` in the Manager class that runs in the main thread and `handleNewObjects(String, List<Object>)` that runs in the listener thread.

My current plan is to make `getObjectList()` a synchronized method:

```
class Manager {

    protected synchronized getObjectList() {
        // Do critical section stuff
    }
}
```

and make `handleNewObjects()` look like this

```
class Listener implements Runnable {
    private final Manager myManager;

    handleNewObjects() {
        synchronized (myManager) {
            // Do critical section stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Will this ensure my critical sections never run simultaneously?
Should I synchronize some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `getObjectList()` was to be a synchronized method, and `myManager` in `Listener` was the same `Manager` instance as the instance that will modify a shared set of objects, then yes it would work.

It is hard to say without knowing the relationships between your existing code to know if there's a better solution for you, however this approach could be seen as somewhat fragile. A change to what object `Manager` locks on would cause `Listener` to not be thread-safe anymore, and if the shared objects the two critical sections modify already exist in Manager, you might as well have Listener call another synchronized in Manager, say `myManager.handleNewObjects()`.

What I mean by a change to what object Manager locks on is if Manager went from:

```
protected synchronized getObjectList() {
    // Do critical section stuff
}
```

to

```
protected getObjectList() {
    synchronized (myPrivateFinalLockObject) {
        // Do critical section stuff
    }
}
```

or

```
protected getObjectList() {
    delegatingWorkToSomeOtherThreadSafeObject.getObjectList();
}
```

Then Listener isn't thread-safe anymore as it doesn't lock it's critical section on the same object anymore.

Comment: What do you mean by "A change to what object Manager locks on"?

Comment: @Stephan Needed code to explain what I meant so I modified the answer to show

Comment: @NESPowerGlove brings up a good point. Basically it comes down to encapsulating the synchronization logic or spreading it out across several classes. When it's spread out, a subtle change in any of the classes that participate in the synchronized operation could result in breakage.  Best to encapsulate it.  Perhaps using ReadWriteLock as Khanna111 suggested or with BlockingQueue.

Answer (score 1):

> Will this ensure my critical sections never run simultaneously?

Yes, but as Quirliom noted, be sure they are the same object.  If you're using any frameworks, beware of framework created proxies.

> Should I synchronize some other way?

Producer-consumer setups are pretty common.  Things get trickier when you have multiples of each.  Rather than reinvent it yourself, you can take a look at some classes that are [built into the platform](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html).  From the Javadocs (not exactly what you're doing, but close):

```
class Producer implements Runnable {
   private final BlockingQueue queue;
   Producer(BlockingQueue q) { queue = q; }
   public void run() {
     try {
       while (true) { queue.put(produce()); }
     } catch (InterruptedException ex) { ... handle ...}
   }
   Object produce() { ... }
 }

 class Consumer implements Runnable {
   private final BlockingQueue queue;
   Consumer(BlockingQueue q) { queue = q; }
   public void run() {
     try {
       while (true) { consume(queue.take()); }
     } catch (InterruptedException ex) { ... handle ...}
   }
   void consume(Object x) { ... }
 }

 class Setup {
   void main() {
     BlockingQueue q = new SomeQueueImplementation();
     Producer p = new Producer(q);
     Consumer c1 = new Consumer(q);
     Consumer c2 = new Consumer(q);
     new Thread(p).start();
     new Thread(c1).start();
     new Thread(c2).start();
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that getObjectsList is a retrieval method with no updates, you could improve on concurrency utilizing ReadWriteLocks. Here the handle* method is the method that updates the underlying list. Please see:
http://ilkinbalkanay.blogspot.com/2008/01/readwritelock-example-in-java.html